# passing arguments in function expression

Tags: javascript

```
(function() {
    var theArg;
     google = function(arg) {
        theArg = arg;
        alert(theArg);
     }

     yahoo = function() {
       alert(theArg);
     }
})();

google("hello");
```

I am not getting the alert in `yahoo` function. What i am missing here and what is going wrong.

Comment: Where in your script do you call yahoo?

Comment: @SnapGravy: I call it from other page, but somehow i am not able to get the alert...

Comment: If you are calling it from a page you should export yahoo window.yahoo = function() ...

Comment: It should work fine, beware of the scope though.http://jsfiddle.net/3dN3n/

Comment: @SnapGravy: Could you explain me or give a code... i think this is the problem i am facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a quick example to the comments in the main question.

Script

```
(function(exports) {

    var theArg, google, yahoo;

    google = function(arg) {
        theArg = arg;
        alert(theArg);
    }

    yahoo = function() {
        alert(theArg);
    }

    exports.yahoo = yahoo; // This is now available to the window

})(window);

// This will set initial value of 
google("Hello World");
```

HTML Page

```
<!-- This should now alert Hello World! -->
<button onclick="yahoo()">Yahoo</button>
```

In my experience if you call this without assigning to window it will not alert anything as the function will be undefined. As mentioned in comments, this is a scope issue.

Comment: Can i pass this instead of window object.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure, outside of a function this would refer to the window I believe. But I am not sure about how it works with anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a function called `yahoo`, but nowhere are you calling it - hence I wouldn't expect you to see this alert.

Answer (score 1):

You never call the `yahoo` function.

This does as you would expect:

```
google("hello");   
yahoo();
```